# Problems using Multipath TCP

Tags: networking, network-manager

I'm setting up a tunnel with Shadowsocks between my machine and an AWS server using Multipath TCP. The AWS server is running version 22.04, and I've tested both version 22.04 and 22.10 on the client machine, and they behaved the same way.

The system is able to create the connection and a subflow for each network connection I have, but when it comes to communication, it only sends data through the main connection and not through the subflows. It only uses the subflows if I disconnect the main connection.

I couldn't find any way to change how NetworkManager manages Multipath TCP. In version 0, I know there was a way to configure it for round-robin and redundancy, but in the native Linux kernel commands, it doesn't work, and I couldn't find anything to control it.

Another issue I have is that after some time, Linux starts closing the subflows and doesn't reopen them unless I restart the connection in question, completely losing redundancy in case of failure.

Is this Multipath TCP support complete or still experimental? I couldn't find much information online, is this how it currently works? If you have any ideas on how to help, I appreciate it.